# Seagate HDD spins up and down constantly

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

so I have a new computer Ryzen 5600X on Gigabyte B550 Aorus Elite v2. Pretty sweet, BUT the secondary HDD Seagate Barracuda 2TB sometimes starts to act weirdly:
spins up and next second spins down again. Repeats around every 5 seconds.
If I open the drive in my computer it spins up and stays on normally as it should.
Windows power management settings say switch off hard drives after 20minutes, so this seems to be something unrelated.

Comment: Just a comment, but in my (anecdotal) experience, Seagate drives seem to be less reliable than some other hard drive brands overall. I wouldn't think your HDD is likely to fail tomorrow (unless perhaps it starts having issues being recognized) but it might be worthwhile to think about making an additional investment in a new internal (non-Seagate) drive and maybe an inexpensive [hard drive docking station](https://www.google.com/search?q=hard+drive+docking+station) for the existing 2TB drive.

Comment: Not that it helps.. but I had this happen with a western digital drive.  I wrote a windows service that pinged the drive every 5 seconds to keep it awake.  I think that all I did was check the drive serial number.. or root directory.. can't remember.  Worked like a charm for many years.

Comment: but I don't want to keep it awake. If I wanted I would just set it in power management to never power down... funnily today I am working and don't notice this behavior. Maybe something triggers it. Need to keep testing...